# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate setMessageBody problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Here's my code:

```
    if (!_mail) {
    _mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    _mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    CGRect mailRect = _mail.view.frame;
    mailRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    mailRect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    _mail.view.frame = mailRect;
    _mail.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

NSString *messageBody = @"text"

[_mail setSubject:@"Book Order"];
[_mail setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];

[self.view addSubview:_mail.view];
```

After this messagebody is not set. Neither the subject. Why? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to remove the _mail.view.frame = mailRect; line.
Somewhy it is not working if I resize it.